# Why is an FCC lattice the reciprocal lattice of a BCC Lattice?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals

This can, of course, be calculated mathematically. However it is difficult for me to believe that this is a pure mathematical coincidence. Perhaps I don't understand reciprocal lattices the way I should. Is there a physical/intuitive way to explain this?

Comment: Physical way? Transform to reciprocal space and see. Intuitive way? Likely your intuition doesn’t work the same way mine does. But note that there are not many lattices to begin with, and both fcc and bcc have high symmetry compared with most, so there reciprocal lattice needs high symmetry as well, limiting the choices.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the sort of answer that you had in mind, but it might help somewhat.

A generic, not-necessarily-cubic crystal with a body-centered symmetry has sixteen generators of translational symmetry: one for each face, and one for each corner (you can think of the symmetry generators as translating the 'center' point of the unit cell.) Each symmetry generator is associated with a non-trivial dual vector that produces a 'trivial' lattice wave (a wave that is constant when restricted to the points of the non-cubic body-centered lattice), and these dual vectors form the vertices of the reciprocal lattice.  Hence, a generic non-cubic body centered lattice has a reciprocal unit cell that qualitatively resembles a warped face-centered cubic lattice (although with a slightly different symmetry from the warped non-cubic body centered cell.) When the body centered crystal possesses additional discrete rotational symmetries associated with the cube/octohedron, the symmetry extends to the reciprocal lattice as well (hence if one is cubic, then so is the other.)

Answer (score 0):

Each primitive vector of the reciprocal basis must be orthogonal to $2$ of the primitive vectors of the lattice basis. And the dot product to the other must be $2\pi$.

The primitive vectors of the FCC lattice go from one of the vertices of the cube until the points at the centre of the faces (nearest neighbours). Considering the edge of the cube equal to $1$, these vectors are:

$(1/2,1/2,0)$, $(0,1/2,1/2)$ and $(1/2,0,1/2)$.

For the BCC lattice, these primitive vectors go from one of the vertices to the centres of the cubes surrounding that vertex (also nearest neighbours). The vectors are:

$(1/2,1/2,-1/2)$, $(1/2,-1/2,1/2)$ and $(-1/2,1/2,1/2)$.

Making the dot products, it is easy to see that each of one of the group is orthogonal to $2$ of the other group (dot product is zero). And the dot product to the remaining is the unit.

About intuition, it is a matter of visualization in 3D that they are really orthogonal, as shown algebraic.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to symmetry, a high symmetry system may keep it's periodic structure even when passing from the starting lattice to its dual lattice, for example considering two dimensional lattices since they are easy to wrap our heads around, a square lattice does not change, while a rectangular one rotate by 90 degrees, passing from a laying rectangle to a standing one, same thing is seen in the hexagonal lattice, it rotates by 30 degrees "not sure" when performing the transition.
So the reason why the square lattice wasn't affected is because it has high symmetry compared to the rectangular case, a rotation by 90 degrees was indeed applied on the square lattice, but the result is also a square lattice.